# How to make Unity inject the same instance for 2 registered interfaces

Tags: c#, multithreading, dependency-injection, unity-container, decorator

I have a class (`Service`) that receives 2 arguments (an `IClient` and an `ICounter`).

I want **Unity** to inject **the same instance for both** (a `Decorator` that implements both interfaces).

**But how?**

And one more thing: I want Unity to inject the same instance to `Service` using a **per-thread basis**. This is, in each a thread, each time `container.Resolve<Service>()` is invoked, the same instance of `Decorator` should be injected to both arguments of `Service`

This is the code I have so far. I only registers the types and it runs, but 3 instances of the Decorator class are created. In this case, with only one thread, only one instance of Decorator should be created.

You can run it with DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/m3PRQz

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            container.RegisterType<IClient>(new InjectionFactory(c => new Decorator(c.Resolve<Client>())));
            container.RegisterType<ICounter, Decorator>();

            container.Resolve<Service>();

            Console.WriteLine(Decorator.NumberOfInstances + " instances of Decorator have been created");
        }
    }

    public class Client : IClient
    {
    }

    public class Decorator : IClient, ICounter
    {
        public static int NumberOfInstances { get; private set; }    
        public Decorator(IClient client)
        {
            NumberOfInstances++;
        }        
    }

    public interface ICounter
    {
    }

    public interface IClient
    {
    }

    public class Service
    {
        public Service(IClient client, ICounter counter)
        {
        }    
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If I wasn't using DI, I would write this code. Keep in mind I don't invoke any method, for simplicity.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = Task.Run(() => CreateService());
        var t2 = Task.Run(() => CreateService());
    }

    private static Service CreateService()
    {
        var decorator = new Decorator(new Client());
        return new Service(decorator, decorator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you would use to compose this object graph if you weren't using a DI container.

Comment: @Steven Please, take a look to edited question. For each thread I will have a Service and a Decorator that is both IClient and ICounter.

Comment: Your decorator might implement `ICounter`, but it only wraps an `IClient`, so it isn't a decorator for `ICounter`. How does this `Decorator` forward the calls to a real `ICounter` in case its `ICounter` methods are used?

Comment: @Steven Well, this class is a Decorator for the IClient only. ICounter is an interface that only provides a integer property (CallCount) that is the times a method was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

register Decorator per thread:

```
container.RegisterType<Decorator>(
    new PerThreadLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionFactory(c => new Decorator(c.Resolve<Client>())));
```

map interfaces to decorator:

```
container.RegisterType<ICounter, Decorator>();
container.RegisterType<IClient, Decorator>();
```